# Trying to get 3 divs floating full lenth of screen while middle div is dynamic

Tags: css, positioning, html

**CSS Markup:**

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    background:#FFAA00;
}
#left {
    position: relative;
    background: url(footer_bg_social2.png) repeat-x 0 -70px;
    overflow:hidden;
    height: 70px;
}
#right {
    position: relative;
    background: url(footer_bg_social2.png) repeat-x 0 -70px;
    overflow:hidden;
    height: 70px;
}
#tab-seperator {
    height: 70px;
}
#tab-seperator div.tab-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 70px;
    float:left;
}
#tab-seperator ul {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#tab-seperator ul li {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
#tab-seperator ul li.start {
    background: url(footer_bg_social2.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    width:22px
}
#tab-seperator ul li.content {
    background: url(footer_bg_social2.png) repeat-x 0 -140px;
}
#tab-seperator ul li.end {
    background: url(footer_bg_social2.png) no-repeat -248px 0;
    width:22px
}
```

**HTML Markup:**

```css
<div id="tab-seperator">    
    <div id="left"> </div>       
    <div class="tab-wrapper">
        <ul>                
            <li class="start"></li>
            <li class="content">testing..length</li>
            <li class="end"></li>                                
        </ul>        
    </div>  
    <div id="right"> </div>    
</div>
```

So I am looking to get the left and right div to make up the full width of my page, varying in size depending how long the middle section grows. Having issues getting this to work...the above solution is getting two lines both making up full page width, ofcourse I want this all on 1 line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `.start` and `.end` elements to span the full widths by specifying a width for the `.content`  `li`.

```
<div id="tab-seperator">    
    <div id="left"> </div>       
    <div class="tab-wrapper">
        <ul id="oneline">                
            <li class="start">[start]</li>
            <li class="content">[testing..length]</li>
            <li class="end">[end]</li>                                
        </ul>        
    </div>  
    <div id="right"> </div>    
</div>

#oneline {display:table;width:100%;background:#555;}
.start, .content, .end {display:table-cell;}
.content {width:50%;background-color:#777;}
```

See here for it in action: http://codepen.io/joe/pen/Ffzqm

Comment: Hey its actually the left and right elements I want to span the full width. As you can see in my post I have a fixed width for start and end and content li is the dynamic one

Answer (score 0):

You can make your divs display as table-cells.  Here's how I have executed it:

```
#tab-seperator{
width:100%;
display:table;
}

#left {
width:auto;
display:table-cell;
}

.tab-wrapper {
width:1000px; /* Whatever you want the main container to be */
display:table-cell;
}

#right {
width:auto;
display:table-cell;
}
```

You can see a live example [HERE](http://beta.mybattlereport.com/)
Just inspect the elements